# How to make Google+ Hangout load in an HTML frame?

Tags: google-plus, frames, google-hangouts

I'm guessing Google has found a way to stop Google+ from loading in an iFrame, because whereas I can put https://www.google.com/ into a page's frame, I can't do the same with https://plus.google.com/.  It just gives a blank page.  I'm trying to embed a hangout in my custom page.  Can anyone tell me why this isn't working and if there is a way to make it work?  All I want to do is add some widgets outside of the Hangout.  Here is the header that Google is returning in Firefox:

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8

X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

P3P CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."

Content-Encoding    gzip

Date    Wed, 28 Sep 2011 07:23:04 GMT

Expires Wed, 28 Sep 2011 07:23:04 GMT

Cache-Control   private, max-age=0

X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff

X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block

Content-Length  674

Server  GSE
```

In Chrome, it just says the page is not responding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, that was dumb... it was staring me in the face:

X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header